# create a two dimensionla array with Java reflection using java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance

Tags: java, javascript, reflection

I need to create a two dimensional array of type `java.lang.String` using the reflection method from JavaScript code which is running inside a java application (inside the rhino scripting engine). This array will be a return value (of a javaScript function) that is used from JavaCode after the function call.

```
function test() {
    var a = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(?, ?);
    // fill the array
    return a;
}
```

I couldn't find the right parameters for the `newInstance` call to create a two diemnsional array of type String.

At the moment I'm working with a workaround, i.e. I create an (outer) array of type `java.lang.Object`of size x and inside a x-length loop a create multiple arrays of type `java.lang.String` each of size y which are assigned to the ''outer' array elements.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is fill in the class and dimensions:

```
var a = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(String.class, x, y);
```

Read more in the javadoc for [`newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int... dimensions)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int...)).

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't read the enough in the refelction API doc. It works perfectly!